# Visual Studio C++ weird exception when calling CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, chromium

I am using CEF3 (chrome embedded framework) in my win32 application, while I am running the application I get a weird error message -

[image]

I am coming from a C# development background, and here in C++ I don't see how I can inspect my error and figure out why it's complaining about my code.
How can I check the error message? If not - how you debug this kind of errors in Visual Studio?

This the code which triggering the error -

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CefRefPtr<CefClient> clientHandler = new ClientHandler();

        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        CefWindowInfo info;
        info.SetAsChild(hWnd, rect);


        // Browser initialization settings.
        CefBrowserSettings settings;


        // Create the new browser window object asynchronously.
        std::string startupUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
        CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(info, clientHandler, startupUrl, settings);
    }
    break;
```

I don't want help in CEF3 (but I will appreciate it) I just want to know how to debug this kind of errors in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The Output window of the debugger tells you what exception was thrown.

Also, you can click "Break" in the dialog that appears and VS will take you to the line on which the exception was thrown. You'll see a yellow arrow to the left of the line.

Finally, if the exception is not fatal, you can catch it and ignore it:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (const SomeException&)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: In the output window I only have "Test.exe has triggered a breakpoint." which is not helpful for debugging this error. I though about catching the exception and checking which exception it's but I don't what is the type of the exception

Comment: The exception is not shown in the dialog, it's shown in the "Output" window (which is on the bottom-left of VS in VS 2010, I don't know about VS 2012).

Comment: OK then maybe no exception is actually being thrown, maybe it's just a breakpoint. Try building in Release mode and see if it runs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems building in Release. The problem was that I didn't called CefInitialize at all.